# jQuery get price from string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a string like this

```
Payment terms:
50.00% - RM9,966.72 - (Before project start)
30.00% - RM5,580.03 - (Upon second review, 70% completion, before next 30% development start)
20.00% - RM3,386.69 - (Before deploy to PROD)
```

With jQuery or JavaScript, I need to retrieve all payment amount (xxxx.xx) with RM at the beginning, regardless of how the string changes.
How do I get (e.g. 9966.72, 5580.03, 3386.69 (decimal form, no comma, not 9,966.72)) in the form of array, with or without regex?

Comment: You've got a pretty clear expression to look for with `RMnnn.nn`. Are you having any particular difficulty using that in a regex?

Comment: I am just weak at regex, so I am not sure how to write to regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const str = `Payment terms:
50.00% - RM966.72 - (Before project start)
30.00% - RM580.03 - (Upon second review, 70% completion, before next 30% development start)
20.00% - RM386.69 - (Before deploy to PROD)`;

const regex = /(?<=RM)[\d]*\.*[\d]*/g;

const result = str.match(regex);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: You could make `RM` a positive look-behind (ie `(?<=RM)`), then you wouldn't have to remove it from the matches later

Comment: @Phil Thank you for such a great suggestion 

Comment: Is there a way to get the result in array form instead of string with commas?

Comment: @TanSiKai Result is in array of string

Comment: Hi, so sorry, what if the payment amount above is a number with commas? How do I get the decimals only? Please check my edited string

Comment: @TanSiKai example please, What do you want to achieve

Comment: I have added explanation to my question. Is there something you still do not understand? Kindly refer to my edited question